# Maximum number of concurrent connections using WebAPI Self Hosting Service - Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a windows service I have written that utilises the SelfHost feature of WebAPI.

I was wondering how many concurrent connections the service can handle if installed on a Windows 7 machine (Enterprise edition)

From the information I can find, when running IIS on windows 7 the maximum number of connections is 20.

Answer (score 0):

Windows client operating systems are not viable as service hosts as Microsoft puts a hard limit on the number of connections they can accept. That is true across all flavors of Windows 7 and 8.